# C# store login session in session class

Tags: c#, forms, session

i want to store the login information `{id,bagian`} so i created `Session.cs` class.
here is the `Session.cs` code

```
 class Session
{
  public Session ()
  {

  }
  public int idnya { get; set; }
  public string bagiannya { get; set; }

    public void saveSession(int id, string bagian)
    {
        idnya = id;
        bagiannya = bagian;
    }

    public void destroySession()
    {
        idnya = 0;            
        bagiannya = "";
    }
}
```

so the `id` will be generated automatically in the following form. however, why does the `id` return 0 ?

[image]

here is my `Tambah` constructor

```
public Tambah()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox2.Text = session.idnya.ToString();
    }
```

here is my `Login` code. iam using `saveSession()` method to store the `id` and `bagian` into `Session.cs` class

[image]

```
  int nomornya = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        string passwordnya = textBox2.Text;
        string bagiannya = comboBox1.Text;


        var data = from a in de.karyawan
                   where a.nomor_karyawan == nomornya &&
                   a.password == passwordnya &&
                   a.bagian == bagiannya
                   select a;

        if (data.Any())
        {
            if (bagiannya.Equals("Admin"))
            {
                cmd.cetakSukses("Login sebagai admin", "Login");
                loginAdmin();
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.cetakSukses("Login sebagai teller", "Login");
                loginTeller();
            }
            main.Show();
            this.Hide();
            session.saveSession(nomornya, bagiannya);
            //MessageBox.Show(session.idnya.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            cmd.cetakGagal("Username atau password salah", "Login");
        }
```

when i call the `idnya` and `bagiannya` value, they show the expected values. but, it went wrong when i call the `Tambah` form.

how to resolve this ?
or is there any alternative way without generating `Session` class manually ?

any help will be apprciated. thanks !

Answer (score 0):

From the picture and the fact that you suggest that the code doesn't crash I guess that "textBox1" is the second TextBox control in the picture. This control contains text "0", so after you parse this text into an integer it will give you 0. After that, you don't modify this variable ("nomornya" whatever this means), so how do you expect it no to be 0? Besides all this, your question is cluttered and unclear.

EDIT: it is still unclear what do you expect to happen and why. What's the scenario? If the ID comes from the user, how is anyone suppose to guess what are you typing into the textBox1 what produces the unwanted results? When does the "id return 0" as you've stated?

Comment: that nomornya refers to parsed textbox1.text in my login form